# Is the $\in$ relation a dyadic, or a monadic, relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, predicate-logic

I believe that it's true (correct me if I'm wrong) that

- When we predicate something of an argument we're saying that that argument is a member of a set intensionally defined just by that predicate?  (I.e. '$Px$' := '$x\in P$ ')
- The $P$ in $Px$ is a monadic relation.
- The '$\in$' in '$x\in P$ ' is a dyadic relation.

It seems strange that the two expressions use different relations despite denoting the same thing. I suspect I'm wrong about one of the three points I listed above. Is there anything that I misbelieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "pure" language of predicate logic (or FOL) there is no symbol $\in$.

The usual "restricted quantifier" symbol : $(\forall x \in A) \ P(x)$ is an *abbreviation* for :

> $\forall x \ (A(x) \to P(x))$.

When we use it for the first-order language of set theory we need only one predicate symbol, the binary $\in$.

With it we can build *atomic* formulae, like : $x \in y$, and sentences, like : $\exists x \forall y \lnot (y \in x)$.

---

The (not trivial) difference is that in "pure" first-order language the expression $P(x)$ is formed with an *individual* variable symbol : $x$ and a unary (monadic) *predicate* symbol : $P$.

In the first-order language of set theory, the expression $x \in y$ is formed with two *individual* variable symbols : $x$ and $y$, and a binary (dyadic) *predicate* symbol : $\in$.

---

The "link" between $P(x)$ and $x \in P$ is thorugh the *semantics*; when we specify an *interpretation* $\mathcal I$ with *domain* $D$ for the language, we have to interpret the *predicate* symbol $P$ with a subset $P^D$ of the *domain*, i.e. $P^D \subseteq D$.

This interpretation assign a meaning to the atomic formula $P(x)$ throug a *variable assignment* function :

> $s : Var \to D$

i.e. a function mapping individual variables to elements of the domain $D$.

The semantic specification for $P(x)$ will be :

> $P(x)$ is satisfied in $\mathcal I$ with $s$ (in symbols : $\mathcal I,s \vDash P(x)$) **iff** $s(x) \in P^D$.

Comment: I always thought set theory with the logical constants just was logic with set theoretic atomic formulae. I didn't know they were different languages. 

Why would anyone bother with predicate logic? Set theory seems more expressive.

Comment: @Hal - first-order set theory **is** "logic with the set theoretic predicate $\in$"... It is not a "different language", but only a "specific" language, with only one dyadic relation symbol and no monadic ones.